# UITabBarController's tabBar showed slower than controller's view

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

Question:I'm using UITabBarController and all is ok. However,When i selected a item,then present a controller in the controller of the item, after dismissing the present controller, and back to first item ,the wired thing was happened:

1.pushed a controller(all is ok)

2.pop the controller of top, the tabBar showed after the first controller's view having showed and with animation.it's wired.

the normal status is tabor should show together with the first controller's view of the first barItem.

Anyone know what should i do?

Thanks Advanced!

My Code is here:

First:initial thirdNav and tabbaritem

```
//MainController.m(extend UITabBarController)
//....
-(YSSJNavigationController *)thirdNav{
    if (!_thirdNav) {
        YSSJLivingViewController *livingViewController = [[YSSJLivingViewController alloc] init];
        [livingViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
        _thirdNav = [[YSSJNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:livingViewController];
        _thirdNav.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
        [_thirdNav setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];

    }
    return _thirdNav;
}
//....
self.thirdNav.tabBarItem = [self  itemWithTitle:[arrayName objectAtIndex:4] image:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayName objectAtIndex:5]] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayName objectAtIndex:4]] ];
self.thirdNav.tabBarItem.tag = 2;
//...other navs' initial
self.viewControllers = @[firstNav,secondNav,self.thirdNav,fourthNav];
```

Second:present a new controller from ThirdNav's root controller
    //YSSJLivingViewController.m
    -(void)p_jumpToLivePage{
        NSDictionary *options = @{
                                  @"gid" : @(-1),
                                  @"gids" : @[],
                                  @"shortContent" : @"",
                                  @"tags" :@[],
                                  @"title" : @"",
                                  @"type" : @"live"
                                  };
        NSMutableDictionary *liveInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:options];

```
    liveInfo = [YSSJTop setLiveInfo:liveInfo];
    NSMutableDictionary *createOption = [liveInfo[@"creator"] mutableCopy];
    NSArray *joinedGroups = liveInfo[@"joinedGroups"];

    createOption[@"liveId"]= liveInfo[@"liveId"];
    [createOption setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:liveInfo];


    VLiveStreamViewController *liveStreamVC = [[VLiveStreamViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    liveStreamVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;


    liveStreamVC.fromChatGroup = @(-1);
    liveStreamVC.createOption = [createOption copy];
    liveStreamVC.joinedGroups = joinedGroups;
    liveStreamVC.needSelectGroup = YES;
    liveStreamVC.delegate = self;


    [self presentViewController:liveStreamVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Third:dismiss controller and switch to front controller

```
//YSSJLivingViewController.m
//dismiss之后会响应这个函数  发出一个通知
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CloseLiveNotification object:nil];
}

//maincontroll.m
//notification's function
-(void)closeLive{
    if (_lastSelectedIndex == 2) {
        _lastSelectedIndex = _frontSelectedIndex;
        [self setSelectedIndex:_frontSelectedIndex];
    }else{
        _lastSelectedIndex = _frontSelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

Then push a controller and pop it,the wired thing happened.....

Answer (score 0):

Oh,It's solved!

After dismissed the controller,i posted a notification to MainController(extend UITabBarController) to switch third item to first item,but the notification's place is error!

error place:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     //...
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CloseLiveNotification object:nil];
     //...
}
```

right place:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     //...
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CloseLiveNotification object:nil];
     //...
}
```

Then all is work right!